# SMPS blown after wrong mains voltage

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, repair

I have one of those 24V/15A SMPS with a switch to select the input voltage (110/220V). It was connected to 220V while the 110V was selected and now it is obviously not working.

I opened it and, apart from the fuse that was completely brown, everything looks fine: all capacitors look normal and there is nothing brownish.

I replaced the fuse and powered it on again, but I got only 13~15v on the output and the relay that bypasses the NTC for in-rush current control keeps turning on and off at around 2Hz.

I have checked the voltage at the retification diodes output and they look ok (310V), desoldered and tested the big smoothing capacitors (rated for 200V) with a multimeter (measured capacitance around 10% less than rated) and checked the diodes on the primary (all good).

So my questions is: what are the main components that could go bad in a situation like this?
I know it might be "everything", but any hints are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest identifying and replacing the controller IC.

Comment: that would be hard. all ICs had their labels removed during manufacturing...

Comment: Suppose you fix it and it works but there's still some component that is "on the edge" (because it got hit by the 220 V but just managed to survive) and that component is going to fail when you're out to buy groceries so you come home and your house is on fire. Would you risk that? I would not and I would just buy a **new power supply**.

Answer (score 2):

The selector switch basically turns the input bridge into a doubler. So it looks like you applied 600+ VDC to the primary.

> what are the main components that could go bad in a situation like this?

The effects of this voltage level can be seen on multiple sections of the circuit:

**- MOV / VDR:** An improperly selected MOV will go short or clamp the input to a much lower value and thus will prevent the circuit to operate even after a replacing the fuse.

**- Primary MOSFETs:** Looking at the power levels, the converter should be a forward or a bridge-type converter. Assuming 650V MOSFETs have been used, they probably have survived.

**- Start-up resistors:** The supply to the controller IC can come from either an aux winding or an independent aux/bias/stby supply. Regardless of where the supply comes from, there should be start-up resistors and these resistors see the full DC voltage at start up. These resistors normally selected for maximum operating voltage of 265Vac, or 375VDC. A voltage of 1.65 times the expected maximum will double the dissipated power across these resistors. If they are cheap resistors then they may have gone open, or at least their resistance may go further than MOhms range due to excessive heat. This will prevent the circuit from starting.

**- Secondary rectifiers *(Including the ones on aux windings)*:** Their voltage stress will be doubled so they may get damaged.

Answer (score 1):

A common input rectifier circuit for a switchable mains SMPS is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwVsxG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the switch open, the bridge rectifier simply puts peak mains voltage on the output caps.

With the switch closed, D2 and D4 are not used, and D1 and D3 voltage double into the output caps.

Unlike a transformer input circuit, which would saturate and limit the output voltage, there is nothing here to limit the output except breakdown of some component. If the diodes and capacitors survived, they would try to put 680 V onto the inverter following, which would probably give it a bad day. Assume one or more of the inverter components have been fried.